# Is there a way to ensure LASSO regularisation retains certain features in R?

Tags: r, predictive-models, lasso, regularization

I am creating a predictive model with a large number of features in R, but would like to prevent basic demographic features from being selected out of the model via LASSO regularisation. Is there a way to achieve this?

e.g. $y = \beta_1 Age + \beta_2 Sex + \beta_3 V_3 + \beta_4 V_4 + \beta_5 V_5 + \beta_6 V_6 +\dots$

Comment: Yes, there is. Just read the glmnet documentation, there is an argument (at least in R version) `penalty.factor`.

Answer (score 1):

Practically, you can use different Lasso coefficients for different parameters, i.e. reformulate your loss function as $$L=\text{MSE}+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i|\beta_i|$$
This enables you to regularize the parameters differently. You can also set some $\lambda_k$ to $0$ for them to avoid any regularization.

Comment: I was thinking more like having the sum skip the indices corresponding to the variables that OP wants to exclude from regularization.

Comment: Right! That’s also included in this definition.